# Como usar SELECT DISTINCT para valores extraídos de uma array de json dentro do metabase usando PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, array, json, postgresql

Estou usando o Metabase, que utiliza PostgreSQL.
Eu tenho uma tabela que possui uma coluna com arrays de json como valores.

Eu extrai os valores da coluna usando a seguinte query, e funcionou:

```
select  (json_array_elements(metadata::json)->>'tribunal') "Tribunal"
from checks 
    join suppliers on checks.supplier_id = suppliers.id
    join buyers on suppliers.buyer_id = buyers.id
where checks.name = 'CRIMINAL_PROCESSES'
```

Mas agora eu preciso usar um disntinct nesse valores, e não estou conseguindo.

Eu fiz duas tentativas, e as duas deram errado:

1. Tentei criar uma CTE com essa query, e depois usei um -`SELECT DISTINC "Tribunal" FROM TABELA(CTE)`-. Não deu certo.
2. Tentei usar a seguinte query:

`select  (json_array_elements(metadata::json)->>'tribunal') "Tribunal" from checks  join suppliers on checks.supplier_id = suppliers.id join buyers on suppliers.buyer_id = buyers.id`

E também não deu certo.
Ambas as tentativas retornaram o seguinte erro:

> ERROR: cannot call json_array_elements on a non-array